# Do we ever get a clue as to the initials H.W. or was this his given name by his biological father?

Tags: analysis, there-will-be-blood

In [***There Will Be Blood***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469494/), do we ever find out (explicitly, or implicitly) the meaning of the initials H.W. (as in Daniel's son, H.W. Plainview)?

Are there any allusions to the meaning or origin of these initials?

Comment: This purely speculative piece does make the HW Bush connection, but again without reference or citation http://www.filmbrain.com/filmbrain/2007/12/there-will-be-b.html still quite interesting though.